# Mercurial: Undo deleted files on branch merge

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a following scenario:

On my `default` branch I have a folder named `Files` containing some files.

1. A branch `b1` was created at `R1`
2. Some files were added to a folder `Files` on branch `b1` at `R2`
3. The folder was renamed from `Files` to `files` ( lowercase ) in `default` branch at `R3`
4. I try to make a branch merge from default to branch `b1` on my Windows machine.

The result I'm getting is:
File changes made to files in folder `Files` are being merged to files in folder `files` - this is OK - thank you, Mercurial :)
BUT
New files created in `b1` are deleted ( probably due to a folder change ), but still tracked. So when I try to commit, I get an error:

```
abort: cannot commit merge with missing files
```

When I try to revert the missing files, I'm also getting an error:

```
abort: uncommitted merge with no revision specified
(use "hg update" or see "hg help revert")
```

So...what should I do next? I believe one scenario is to clone the repo from it's clean state and manually copy over the missing files?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: yes, it does show status as deleted, but untracked list of files. I'm questioning how do I restore them - as they weren't supposed to be removed. What I did is just copied them manually from a clone of clean repo, but that's a stupid workaround